# Restore passwords from Google Chrome login file

Tags: google-chrome, decryption, win32

I have reinstalled Windows recently and as a result lost all of my login data for Google Chrome with sites' passwords. A little research told me that I have to be under the exact same windows profile to decrypt the file via Google Chrome. Moreover, it is said that password blobs within login file are encrypted with 3DES by current windows profile password. Could it be decrypted with other means provided that I remember the password?

Comment: Try [ChromePass - Chrome Browser Password Recovery for Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html). You may add an exception to the tool in your Antivirus software, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work. It is not displaying my previous passwords.

Comment: Have you tried the `Advanced Options` window - `F9` and point to your Chrome user data folder?

Comment: Yes, the first thing I did. It shows logins, dates, everything except for passwords.